# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException in the coding

Tags: java

I'm pretty sure these questions have been asked millions of times but unfortunately, I cannot find the answer.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.bluebitgames.visualnovel.Game.initStatesList(Game.java:30)
    at org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.init(StateBasedGame.java:164)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:390)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:314)
    at com.bluebitgames.visualnovel.Game.main(Game.java:77)
```

I know that the java.lang.NullPointerException means that the variable has a null value and so I must change it but I really have no idea.

```
package com.bluebitgames.visualnovel;

import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.UnicodeFont;
import org.newdawn.slick.font.effects.ColorEffect;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class Game extends StateBasedGame {
        public static final int SCREEN_WIDTH        = 1024;
        public static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT        = 640;
        public static final String title        = "Visual Novel";
        public static final String version        = "";
        public static final String vDate        = "03/07/12";

        // States
        public static final int menu  = 0;
        public static final int play  = 1;

        // Main font
        public static UnicodeFont font;

        public Game(String title) {
                super(title);
                this.addState(new Play(play));
        }

        public void initStatesList(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {
                this.getState(menu).init(gc, this);     //line 30
                this.getState(play).init(gc, this);
                this.enterState(menu);
        }



        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public static UnicodeFont mainFont(int size, String name) {
                if(name.equals("default")) {
                        name        = "tempesta";
                }
                UnicodeFont font;
                try {
                        font        = new UnicodeFont("res/fonts/"+name+".ttf", size, false, false);
                        font.addAsciiGlyphs();
                        font.addGlyphs(400, 600);
                        font.getEffects().add(new ColorEffect(java.awt.Color.WHITE));
                        font.loadGlyphs();
                        return font;
                } catch(SlickException e) {
                        System.out.println("Could not load font.");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                String os        = System.getProperty("os.name");
                if(os.contains("Windows")) {
                        os        = "windows";
                } else if(os.contains("Mac")) {
                        os        = "macosx";
                } else {
                        os        = "linux";
                }

                System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath",System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/lib/natives/"+os);
                AppGameContainer agc;
                try {
                        agc        = new AppGameContainer(new Game(title+" v"+version));
                        agc.setDisplayMode(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, false);
                        //agc.setFullscreen(true);
                        agc.setTargetFrameRate(60);
                        agc.setShowFPS(true);
                        agc.setVSync(true);
                        agc.start();      //line 77
                } catch(SlickException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

(The StateBasedGame and the AppGameContainer are classes of a .jar called 'Slick' and I am not sure how to bring the coding up for it. Sorry!)

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

EDIT: So sorry about that. just edited that.

Comment: As with any NPE question you must have read, the key is identifying which line is throwing it. So which one is it? Which line is line 30, `Game.java:30` as the exception stacktrace tells you?

Comment: As I thought, then perhaps my answer and that of Elliott are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the "Menu" State. I suggest trying to add such a state in your constructor, it should be as easy as something like this

```
public Game(String title) {
  super(title);
  this.addState(new Play(play));
  this.addState(new Menu(menu)); // Assuming you have a Menu somewhere...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer. I'm a real noob when it comes to Java since I just switched from 1 type of coding from another. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Slick2D, but you appear to be adding a Play State but not a Menu State in your constructor, and it seems the NPE is thrown when you attempt to call a method on the Menu State. I SWAG, but perhaps you should initialize the Menu State as well in the constructor.

1000 pardons and a deleted answer if this is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I made a big mistake on my half. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Colby, why everyone knows what SWAG is, a Silly Wild Ass,...essment Guess. Yeah, that;s the tick!